# How to create option inside select tag dynamically with ajax response text in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have html code like this for drop down list.

```
<select id="province" onchange="get_twn()">
<option value="western">Western</option>
<option value="southern">Southern</option>
</select>

<select id="towns" name="towns">
</select>
```

And this is my ajax code for `get_twn`.

```
function get_twn(){

    var e = document.getElementById('province');    
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var xmlhttp;
    alert('i came');
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){          
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //window.location.assign("login.php");
                var val = xmlhttp.responseText; 
                var selectList = document.getElementById('towns');          
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = val;
                option.text = val;
                selectList.appendChild(option);

            }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php?a="+val,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is the php code `test.php`.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["a"])){

        $result = $dba->get_twn($_REQUEST["a"]);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $val = $row['name'];
            echo $val;          
        }
}
```

This code working well but there is little mistake. When this code execute it will create option tag but all values combine with each other and create only one option tag.Like this. [image: problem] However it should appear like this.[image]

Comment: You have it completly wrong.

Comment: @Legionar wrong? what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your PHP to this:

**test.php:**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["a"])){

        $result = $dba->get_twn($_REQUEST["a"]);

        $towns = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $towns[] = $row['name'];    
        }

        echo json_encode($towns);
}
```

**And in your function get_twn change this:**

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){          
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            //window.location.assign("login.php");
            var selectList = document.getElementById('towns');    

            var jsonData = JSON.parse(val);

            for (var i in jsonData) {
              var option = document.createElement('option');
              option.value = jsonData[i];
              option.text = jsonData[i];
              selectList.appendChild(option);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Wait a sec. I am writing it :)

Comment: yhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh ... its working well ... thanks... awesome.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["a"])){

        $result = $dba->get_twn($_REQUEST["a"]);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option>".$row['name']."</option>";        
        }
}
```

in ajax

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //window.location.assign("login.php");
                var val = xmlhttp.responseText; 
                var selectList = document.getElementById('towns');          
                selectList.appendChild(val);

            }
```

Comment: I don't downgrade but I guess it's better to fill the <option> in the ajax request. The **test.php** return json. You put html.

Comment: The solution is correct but it would be better to add option tag in javascript while appending data .